# Dropdown não se ajusta a tela

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Olá,
estou começando minha migração para o Bootstrap 4 e estou tentando fazer um dropdown alinhado na estrema direita do layout. O problema é que ao clicar no menu ele não se ajusta a tela e "sai" para fora do layout. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Segue o código abaixo

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MARCA</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite" aria-controls="navbarSite" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link scrollSuave" href="#">LINK</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link scrollSuave" href="#sobre">LINK</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link scrollSuave" href="#equipe">LINK</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
       </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">LINK</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">LINK</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Bootstrap 4 tem uma classe que alinha o menu. Basta inserir a classe `dropdown-menu-right` na div do dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

[Documentação de alinhamento de menu.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MARCA</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite" aria-controls="navbarSite" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link scrollSuave" href="#">LINK</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link scrollSuave" href="#sobre">LINK</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link scrollSuave" href="#equipe">LINK</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
       </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">LINK</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">LINK</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```